# post php variable in ajax (no jQuery)

Tags: php, ajax

I guess this is simple question, but not for me.
I have got simple calendar, where is only month:

```
<div id="calendar">
<?php
$month_num=date('m');
echo $month_num . " ";
echo '<span onclick="next(this.value);" value="' . $month_num . '";> &gt; </span>';
?>
</div>
```

my script is:

```
function next(str) {

xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML = this.responseText;
   }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST","test3.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("n=" + str);
}
```

and `test3.php` is:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['n'])) {
    $n = $_POST['n'];
}
if (isset($n)) { 
    echo $n + 1;} 
?>
```

Problem is, `$n` is undefined and result is "1" . I guess there should be some nice simple way how  to post `$n`.

Thank you.

Comment: Any error in browser console when this request is happening?

Comment: `span` element does not have `value` attribute. Show what information is sent (from dev tools params and Headers tabs). Also `$n + 1` may lead to wrong result as all `POST` and `GET` are only strings.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "result is 1"? Because if $n was really undefined, you'd got no echo at all...

Comment: If I use `<button>`  which has `value` attribute, everything works. I just wanted to use simple `<span>`. @Justinas

Comment: I see only "1" in `<div id="calendar">`. If I echo only `$n`, all I can see is word "undefined". @Salketer

Comment: Still, there's something fishy, where is that 1 coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A span does not have a value attribute according to specifications. So you will have a hard time access it in javascript. Try using the data-* attributes for that.

```
echo '<span onclick="next(this.getAttribute(\'data-value\'));" data-value="' . $month_num . '";> &gt; </span>';
```

May I also suggest that, since you are posting, and relying on a click event, a button would be much more appropriate.